# How to draw a rectangle over an image using onTouchevent in android?

Tags: android, canvas, touch-event

How to draw a rectangle over an image using onTouchEvent?

But the rectangle will not be overlapped by the image view?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need! Replace your ImageView(I'm assuming that by image you mean ImageView) for a canvas, and draw it over your canvas!

To draw as you touch create a Path while touching and on the onDraw method keep drawing your path! I didn't write the following code, it was taken from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201026064852/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/06/drawing-with-canvas-in-android.html).

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  synchronized (_thread.getSurfaceHolder()) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
      path = new Path();
      path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
      path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
    }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
      path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
    }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
      path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
      _graphics.add(path);
    }
    return true;
  }
}
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   //Draw your image as bitmap
   canvas.drawBitmap(your_image, 0, 0, null); 
  //Draw your path
  for (Path path : _graphics) {                 
    //canvas.drawPoint(graphic.x, graphic.y, mPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
  }
}
```